# Intellij 13 ADB not responding

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, intellij-13

Launching ADB in intellij,says ADB not responding.you can wait more, or kill adb.exe.process 
manually and click Restart..how do i fixed this?.I really could not run my android project.I am using windows 7...I tried to run command ADB KILL-SERVER but it doesn't work at all.

Thank you.

Comment: if you run the command `adb kill-server` make sure the path to ADB is specified in your system path-variable. Alternatively, put the full path before adb.exe

Comment: Please stop all. Then start IntelliJ first. Next, start device. Finally, run your app.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to get rid of this message

1. use this commands
   (adb kill-server) and 
   (adb devices)
2. kill adb from Task Manager and start it again (similar to 1)
3. be sure that debugging mode is enabled on your device
4. restart your device
5. restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, then start task manager (ctl+alt+del press) and from process list select adb.exe and stop or kill. Works for me :)